# Why does stringstream not move to next set of characters when cout?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
string inputLine = "1 2 3";
stringstream stream(inputLine);

// Case One
int x, y, z;
stream >> x;
stream >> y;
stream >> z;
// x, y, z have values 1, 2, 3

// Case Two
cout << stream << endl;
cout << stream << endl;
cout << stream << endl;
// All 3 print out 1
```

For the above code, why is it when you assign to an int, stringstream moves to the next set of characters, but not with cout?

Actual code:
I'm compiling this on a mac using g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string inputLine = "1 2 3";

    stringstream stream(inputLine);

    // Case One
    int x, y, z;
    stream >> x;
    stream >> y;
    stream >> z;
    // x, y, z have values 1, 2, 3

    // Case Two
    cout << stream << endl;
    cout << stream << endl;
    cout << stream << endl;
}
```

Comment: the handwaving answer is: because `cout` works on a `const string&` while `stream operator >>` is not `const` but it "consumes" the characters in the stream

Comment: `cout << stream << endl` doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: @T.C. : Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I can't get case two to compile. Which headers did you use?

Comment: @flatmouse : #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

Comment: What compiler? That should not compile. Yours apparently has a strange overload. Or, you actually couted `x`. Where's your [MCVE]?

Comment: I can't make it work with Visual Studio, [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfe7b9a20a6067a4) or [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/506df5e9a86e98f2)

Comment: I've updated my question with the actual code I'm running.

Comment: Are you sure this is `C++11`?

Comment: @T.C. what does`cout << stream << endl` do?

Comment: What version of g++ are you using?

Comment: [This compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e032bc98ad027bf). Strange.

Comment: @flatmouse In C++98, it calls `basic_ios::operator void*` (which is a primitive version of the safe bool idiom).

Comment: @NathanOliver How can I check the version?

Comment: @Meyyappan From the command like you can use `g++ -v`

Comment: Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: @Meyyappan It looks like you have g++ 4.2.1.  You may want to consider upgrading to get a more conformant compiler.  g++ is up to version 6 now.

Comment: @NathanOliver No, this is Mac's clang-masquerading-as-gcc, with a really outdated libstdc++ that is not actually used by default.

Comment: @T.C. I didn't know they did that.  I haven't used a mac in about 20 years.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't compile but does due to a bug ([#56193](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56193)) in your standard library implementation, which is not fully C++11-compliant.

**The stream is converting to a `bool` representing its state; `cout` is printing `1` for `true`.**

- Change your integers and you'll see the output is still `1`.
- Or, add `std::boolalpha` to `std::cout` and you'll see `true` instead of `1`.

The crux of it is that your `std::cout << stream` is not actually printing anything relating to the contents of the stream buffer. That's not how you extract data from a stream.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: Still compiles using gcc-5.1: http://ideone.com/lhgWcP. Using `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` makes the compilation fail however.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: Of course. That was assumed. This question is tagged C++11.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: It would require C++11 mode at least, yes.

Comment: Actually, this is libc++. GCC/libstdc++ does something different (has an `operator void*`, prints a pointer). libc++ just macro's away the `explicit` on the `operator bool` in C++98 mode.

Comment: @DarkFalcon It appears that OP isn't actually compiling as C++11, despite the tag...